# Pandas grouping by multiple columns and putting results into a map as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of the format

```
|Col1|Col2|Count|Day  |
|----|----|-----|-----|
| A  |  C |  1  | Mon |
| A  |  C |  3  | Tue |
| A  |  C |  5  | Wed |
| A  |  D |  7  | Mon |
| B  |  C |  2  | Mon |
| B  |  D |  4  | Tue |
```

I want to group by the first two columns, and create a dictionary of the counts per day as a new column grouping the original rows, and throw away the origional Count and Day columns. I want my result to look like

```
|Col1|Col2|dateCounts                   |
|----|----|-----------------------------|
| A  |  C |{"Mon":1, "Tue": 3, "Wed": 5}|
| A  |  D |{"Mon":7}                    | 
| B  |  C |{"Mon":2}                    |
| B  |  D |{"Tue":4}                    |
```

I could do something like adding the column to each row, drop the Count and Day columns and then drop duplicates on the frame, but I'm struggling on getting the extra dateCounts column to work nicely. Is this possible using the `df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2']).apply()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `apply`:

```
df.groupby(['Col1', 'Col2'])\
   .apply(lambda x: dict(zip(x.Day, x.Count))).reset_index(name='dateCounts')

  Col1 Col2                      dateCounts
0    A    C  {'Wed': 5, 'Tue': 3, 'Mon': 1}
1    A    D                      {'Mon': 7}
2    B    C                      {'Mon': 2}
3    B    D                      {'Tue': 4}
```

Comment: Ahh I had something like this but I was missing the `zip`, perfect!

Comment: @TheHCA No problem! Also, congrats on 15 rep, you can now up vote answers ;-)

Comment: Great answer. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank you sir :)